# Select rows with multiple occurrences over multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

DB: SQL Server 2008

I want to select `id, title` and `userid` from a table if that userid occurs more than once across 2 tables.

So if a user has 2 records in locations table, and 1 in artists table, i want to return the id, title and userid of all 3 records.

This is what I have now, but it returns 0 records.

When I leave out the "having count(userid)>1" part, I get ALL 400 records in all tables.

```
select userid,id,title from (
select id,title,userid from locations l
union
select id,title,userid from artists a
) as info
group by userid,id,title
having count(userid)>1
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Union filters out duplicates, did you try UNion all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;WITH combined AS (
  SELECT id, title, userid FROM locations
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, title, userid FROM artists
)
SELECT *
FROM combined c
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT userid
    FROM combined
    GROUP BY userid
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  ) g ON c.userid = g.userid
```

Get the non-unique `userid` list from the UNION sub-query and join it back to the subquery on `userid`. The sub-query is implemented only once, as a CTE.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
select userid,id,title 
from 
( select id,title,userid from locations l union select id,title,userid from artists a )
as grabfromthis
where userid in (
select userid
( select id,title,userid from locations l union select id,title,userid from artists a )
as info 
group by userid having count(userid)>1)
```

Comment: Ok, that does the trick. However over the coming months more tables to join will be added. That would really complicate this statement. Is there an easier way to write this statement which provides the flexibility to join future tables?

Comment: Well either try Andriy M:s way below, or you could make a view which contains your tables.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the above slightly to make it just a bit more slick:

```
WITH combined AS
(
SELECT id from t1
UNION ALL
SELECT id FROM t2
etc...
)
SELECT id, count(id) as numOccurrences
FROM combined
GROUP BY id
HAVING count(id) > 1
```

The difference being that this will show you just how many times your number is repeated.

You could also add

```
ORDER BY numOccurrences to chop down your worst offenders first
```